# java scripting with mozilla rhino and memory management problem

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

I'm building an javascript api that will call some java objects using mozilla rhino.

Everything is good and nice, however I want to avoid unlimited looping that could slow my java application.

for example (in javascript):

```
while(true) doSomething(); // doSomthing will call a method in java
```

In modern browsers after a certain time an error appears telling the script is making the application to run slow, and if I want to continue and stop script.

I want to implement this on my java application if it's possible, but I don't know how.
The only solution I can think about is to count the number of methods are being called per second , and if it's a huge number to stop the script. DO you have any other ideas?

Comment: I don't understand something - do you actually need to call this method continually? Or are you attempting to implement some sort of timeout mechanism that cancels `doSomething()` if it executes for more than N seconds?

Comment: @matt b    The javascript code part will not be implemented by me. it will be by third party developers . What I want is not to give them total freedom since my java applications is actually a server based one, and I don't want to slow down my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting the method calls won't work for code that doesn't call any methods, like:

```
while (true) {
    i++;
}
```

I *think* what you want is [observeInstructionCount().](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.html#observeInstructionCount%28int%29) Also see the [discussion here](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/c8309c84dec9274b) - some of the stuff that they're discussing looks a little iffy, but it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the application multithreaded you could spawn a new thread handling each call from javascript. at the start of the thread you record the start time, and create some timeout logic to go with that.

```
    public void doJavaScript() {
      final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      final long timeout = 1000;
      new Thread(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
             while ((start + timeout) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                ... do work ...
             }
          }
      }.start();
    }
```